# Python - How to open n different json files and just append. once

Tags: python, json, for-loop

What I am trying to do is that I want be able to print out n times pending on how many json files I have in the folder while it prints out all these data for each json BUT it should only add to old_list once.

My code I have coded is following:

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'How', 'Are', 'You']
new_list = ['Im', 'Fine', 'Today', 'You']

    while True:

        if new_list not in old_list:
            directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
            for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
                filename = os.fsdecode(file)
                if filename.endswith(".json"):
                    with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
                        data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())

                        data_list = []


                        data["attachments"][0]["footer"] = str(
                            data["attachments"][0]["footer"] + ' | ' + datetime.now().strftime(
                                '%Y-%m-%d [%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + "]")

                        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        print(data)

                        old_list.append(new_list)
```

The problem right now I am having is that it is adding to the list n times depending on how many json files I have and what I want to make is that it should print out all the json but only add to the list once instead of n times.

My question in that case is: How can I be able to add the list only once but still be able to print out all these jsons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `while True` which causes your code print out non stop. Moreover, `if new_list not in old_list:` is not a right way to compare two lists:

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'How', 'Are', 'You']
new_list = ['Im', 'Fine', 'Today', 'You']
data_list = []
directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
for newLst in new_list:
  if newLst in old_list:
    for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
                    with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
                        data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())          
                        data["attachments"][0]["footer"] = str(
                            data["attachments"][0]["footer"] + ' | ' + datetime.now().strftime(
                                '%Y-%m-%d [%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + "]")

                         print(data)

     data_list.append(newLst) # make sure to what you're ganna append
```

Note that I'm assuming the rest of your code is working well.

Comment: Isn't the problem actually that the append shouldn't be in the for loop?

Comment: Yes that's true, edited. But I just confused if he\she wants to append to the `data_list` or  `old_list`

Comment: Oh okey! But lets assume that if I want to run `while True` - etc if I change old_list and new_list with a txt file which constantly changes, Wouldn't a while True be needed then

Comment: You can add again `while True` at the top of your code, however the problem is that, it'll print out unless you break out the loop because the condition always is met. I don't know what do you mean by txt file?,If you mean changing the `new_list` elements with txt file names like , `file.txt`, then that would be a different story and you should change a bit your code.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot about break, In your case where you print `print(data)` I could just add a break after that I assume ?

Comment: Yes that will break the `while True` loop. However, I think you don't need that loop because I put a for loop at the top of the code which literally is saying for each element in `new_list` if there is the same element in the `old_list` add that element to `data_list` and once you iterated through all `new_list` list, break out automatically. Even if you change the name of  `new_list` or `old_list` nothing going to happen, that comparison will run properly.